# How to mount a .vmdk VMWare virtual harddisk outside of the virtual machine

Tags: hard-drive, vmware-player, vmdk

I've got the virtual harddisk (VMWare .vmdk file) of an old (crashed) virtual machine. How can I open this to extract files without booting from it or attaching it to a virtual machine?

I know Windows 7 can mount .vhd files as additional harddisks, is there a way or tool to do this with an vmdk file?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Download the following:
[VMware Disk Mount Utility](https://my.vmware.com/web/vmware/details?productId=46&downloadGroup=WKST-550-DISK-MOUNT-UTL) << The rest is all self-explanatory.

If you need more help: [Click Here To Read Stepwise Instructions](http://www.vladan.fr/mounting-your-vmdk-disks-directly-to-your-windows-box-how-to/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'll mark it as the right answer, but I can't install the disk mount utility, because it fails with error 1603 and the kb entry for this error doesn't help ... http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1009167

Comment: Hi, Hinek, the Microsoft KB link is better: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/834484

Comment: This page is 404

Comment: @deed02392 Updated the links, thanks for bringing it to my attention.

Comment: @adeelx And the link is once again dead. Here is the updated one: https://my.vmware.com/web/vmware/details?downloadGroup=WKST-550-DISK-MOUNT-UTL&productId=47